# A set $A$ which satisfies $A\approx A\cup\left\{x\right\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be a set such that $A\approx A\cup\left\{x\right\}$ for all $x$, ($\approx \leftrightarrow$ of the same cardinality). I need to prove that this set has a countable subset, not assuming the axiom of choice. I am actually clueless on how to do this, the connection seems very abstract for me, and would like a hint on this one.

Comment: What does $\approx$ mean here?

Comment: Does "$\approx$" mean "equinumerous"?

Comment: Yes sorry, I corrected myself

Comment: You're one of my students, aren't you?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Will that present a problem?

Comment: No, not at all. See you Thursday.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What's on Thursday?

Comment: Magic, what else?

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that there is an injection $f$ from $A\cup\{x\}$ into $A$. But the range of the injection misses $x$ (because it's not in $A$, otherwise the claim is trivial).

Using the fact that $f(x)\in A$, deduce that for every $n\neq m$, $f^n(x)\neq f^m(x)$. From this conclude the wanted conclusion.

Comment: By $f^n$ do you mean iterations?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.